# How to remove <hr> that immediately follows a <hr>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML markup that I am unable to alter.

**Example**

```
<p>
  TEXT 1
  <hr>some text
  <hr>
  <hr>TEXT 2
  <hr>some text
</p>
```

I would like to remove any `hr` that immediately follows another `hr` without text between them. As you can see from the snippet below, that extra `hr` is causing a double line.

I don't think this is possible with CSS. I tried using adjacent (+) selector but realised it obviously won't work.

I looked at using [jQuery `:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/), but as `hr` is self-closing I'm finding it hard to target.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

**Snippet**

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
hr {
  border-top: 3px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #CCC
}
hr + hr {
  /* display: none; // doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<p>
  TEXT 1
  <hr>some text
  <hr>some more text
  <hr>even more text
  <hr>
  <hr>TEXT 2
  <hr>some text
  <hr>some more text
  <hr>even more text
</p>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest to use `span` tags to wrap each text-segment, but I missed the first line of your question. However, `hr` in `p` is not valid HTML, so you might want to reconsider your options about the *"unable to alter"* part. IMO, you are unlikely to get a consistent solution, as your faulty markup might be interpreted differently across browsers.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Thanks John, I saw your answer before removed. I wasn't aware it was invalid. It appears to work visually on the major browsers - is it an accessibility issue?

Comment: It's a root semantic issue that will likely keep causing minor issues until fixed. Most browsers will fix it on-the-fly when rendering, but yes, accessibility is one of the areas possibly affected. The other one is SEO.

Comment: maybe you could use regular expressions to look whether an `<hr>` element has a text character after it, or if it has `line break` or a `<` after it

Comment: @NateBeers Ah yes, the good ol' fix-it-with-regex solution. :) Well, the markup is already invalid, so what's the worst that can happen?

Comment: @JohnWeisz Cheers for the info, I'll see what I can do about changing it...

Comment: @JohnWeisz Well, when you can't change the html, your options are relatively limited.

Comment: As noted in my comment in the accepted answer.. I can avoid hr completely and get the same effect by styling the newly created span elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could programatically wrap the text nodes with `span` elements and then hide the sibling `hr` elements using the initial selector that you suggested, `hr + hr`. In doing so, the text nodes will be accounted for since they are now `span` elements, and the adjacent `hr` elements will be hidden.

As a side note, the HTML is invalid since `hr` elements can't be nested in `p` elements. For the sake of this example, I replaced the `p` element with a `div`, but it would still work with the `p` element and the HTML technically wouldn't have to be changed.

```js
$('.parent-element').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim() !== '';
}).wrap('<span/>');
```

```css
hr {
  border-top: 3px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #CCC
}
hr + hr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent-element">
  TEXT 1
  <hr>some text
  <hr>some more text
  <hr>even more text
  <hr>
  <hr>TEXT 2
  <hr>some text
  <hr>some more text
  <hr>even more text
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. I will test it and post back... thanks

Comment: Actually, this solution allows me to just hide the hr completely and style the spans using display: block and border property. :)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `:nth-child()` selector. So, in your case you would want to use the `:nth-child(even)`

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
hr {
  border-top: 3px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #CCC
}
hr:nth-child(even) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  TEXT 1
  <hr>some text
  <hr>some more text
  <hr>even more text
  <hr>
  <hr>TEXT 2
  <hr>some text
  <hr>some more text
  <hr>even more text
</p>
```

Comment: Using even removes some necessary hr tags. I could use nth-child if the extra hr position was known - however text will be dynamically generated and this duplication may occur multiple times. Thanks though